# What is the official way to extend postinst scripts a la debconf?

Tags: package-management, software-installation

I have a project name [snaplogger](https://github.com/m2osw/snaplogger) that I use to send logs to files, syslog, the console, or a remote computer (what syslogd does but with many more features).

Whenever another project wants to use the `snaplogger`, it's expected to create a log sub-directory. For example, my [communicatord](https://github.com/m2osw/communicatord) project does that:

```
PACKAGENAME=communicatord
USERNAME=communicatord
GROUPNAME=communicatord

[...snip...]

LOGDIR=/var/log/${PACKAGENAME}
LOGFILE=${LOGDIR}/${PACKAGENAME}.log
mkdir -p ${LOGDIR}
touch ${LOGFILE}
chown ${USERNAME}:${GROUPNAME} ${LOGFILE}
chmod 640 ${LOGFILE}
```

What I would like to do is move the last 6 lines to a script that the `snaplogger` project provides. Then the `communicatord` would just use a function that the script defined. Maybe something like this:

```
prepare-snaplogger ${PACKAGENAME} ${USERNAME} ${GROUPNAME} true
```

The `true` at the end means we also want a secure log sub-folder.

Since the postinst script is run with root, it can create all of that whereas the service will run as itself (i.e. I have a `communicatord` user) so it would not be able to create those folders.

My question here is: is there a documented way of providing such extension scripts in Debian and/or Ubuntu?

My idea is that each project should provide such under `/usr/share/<project-name>/[debconf/?]`. But maybe we can use the `/var/share/debconf/...` folder?

---

As a result, I would have one additional line to source that file like the following which would appear near the start of the `communicatord.postinst` script:

```
. /usr/share/snaplogger/debconf
```

Comment: Private scripts for a package's internal usage typically go in some `libexec` folder, which on Debian (and hence Ubuntu) is `/usr/lib/<package>` (e.g., see the tons of binaries in `/usr/lib/git-core/`). Put your private scripts from `snaplogger ` in `/usr/lib/snaplogger`, have the `communicatord` package depend on `snaplogger` and you should be able to use `/usr/lib/snaplogger/<whatever>` in the `communicatord`'s postinst script.

Comment: Addtionally, use `install` instead of `mkdir`,`chown`,`chmod`.

Comment: @Marco Note that the `chown`/`chmod` are for the file I `touch`, not the `mkdir`. So `install` is not that useful in this case.

Comment: Shouldn't syslog be the only one writing files in `/var/log` ? But this is off-topic.